# 2 way to call a resource in Flask-Restful?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I'm learning and using Python, Flask and Flask-Restful for traineeship and I got a question :

Right now I've something like this

```
  class CheckTXT(Resource):
  def get(self):

    import dns.resolver

    dmn = request.args.get('dmn')

    answers = dns.resolver.query(dmn, 'TXT')

    c = []

    for rdata in answers:
        for txt_string in rdata.strings:
            c.append(txt_info(dmn, txt_string))

    end = time.time()
    tm = end - start

    return lookup("TXT", dmn, c, tm)
```

and

```
api.add_resource(CheckTXT, '/lookup/txt')
```

I'd like to call it by 2 way :

`lookup/txt?dmn=stackoverflow.com`

`/lookup/txt/stackoverflow.com`

The first one is working but I don't know how to do the second or even if it's possible.

Someone can help me ? 
Thanks for your attention and your patience ! You're helping a young padawan ahah

Comment: Don't know Flask-Restful, but in pure Flask, you can use routes with variables, see flask docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#variable-rules

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use below as endpoint and possible with flask resful

```
/lookup/txt/stackoverflow.com
```

for that you need to add resources like

`api.add_resource(CheckTXT, '/lookup/txt/<string:name>')` and you can access that field in your implementation like below

```
class CheckTXT(Resource):
  def get(self,name):
      print name
```